# Does triggering Guardian Angel reset Darius' Ult?

Tags: league-of-legends

Everybody knows that if you kill an enemy champion with Daruis' ultimate, the cooldown will be reset and you would have another 12 seconds (I think) to dunk some more Teemos and (fill in your most hated champion).

Now, if the enemy you ult has a Guardian Angel and you would "kill" that person so his Guardian Angel goes off, would that also count as a kill so I can ult that person again within 12 seconds?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The cooldown will not be reset if you trigger a GA passive with it**

Technically the champion with GA doesn't get revived. His health stops at 1 (similar to trynda ult) and he is then healed for 30% of their max health after being invulnerable for a short amount of time. You also won't get any other on-kill procs (Varus Passive Attack Speed, Kata/Yi CD resets) if your opponent has GA.

The same rules apply for Zilean ult.